# Angular2 on js error stops rendering

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Angualar2 in my project. Whenever there is a console error(any javascript error), the  whole page stops rendering and there is only a white screen rendered. Even the url is not updated, as the url in the address bar (not the page content) reverts back to the previous page which got rendered. Please let me  know, if I can somehow reflect the latest url (where the js error occured) instead of the previous route in the address bar.

Comment: Please show us relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs that directly impacts angular operation, it will not load the rest of your angular modules further.

Obviously, if you're using angular router, it's not going to function like a router after your error.